# how to write an ajax call to a controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, controller, salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I have an ajax call on some client side java script and I want it too call to a controller too set a value too true on button click, I am very new to how ajax works.

In my controller, I have a server.append that is called 'Begin'

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-button', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
       //here is where I dont know how to call to the controller
    })
});
```

I know I may have some stuff missing but this is what I am familiar with at the moment.

I want the ajax to connect to the controller function and in my controller function, set a value too true.

Comment: Would you please provide a more comprehensive codebase? I mean what is `controller` in your case? Are you using a MVC pattern on the backend side?

Comment: The URL specifies which controller function to call. You use `data:` to pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

To make an AJAX call to a controller function in JavaScript, you need to specify the URL of the controller action in the url property of the `$.ajax()` function. Additionally, you need to provide the necessary data to the server using the `data` property.

This is the codebase you might use as the boilerplate:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-button', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action', // replace with the actual URL of your controller action
        type: 'POST',
        data: { value: true }, // set the value to true
        success: function(response) {
            // handle the successful response from the server
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // handle the error
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```